# Cpanel and Tomcat 7 servlet mapping

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cpanel, web.xml

I try run servlet on cpanel tomcat 7 but seems it doesnt work. When i run servlet in jsp file that is ok but mapping servlet doesnt work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.i_do2.java.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>indexp.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

when I run www.mydomain.com/TestServlet I got Error 404 not found, it seems that tomcat on cpanel dont read web.xml file, can you help me configurate this inside cpanel?

Context is set as root "/"

Comment: What does your `META-INF/context.xml` file look like? The ROOT context should have a `""` (i.e. empty string) path, not `/`.

Comment: I set empty string and test it but still I can not run servlet over mapping :(, I thik that is something by cpanel/tomcat configuration..

Comment: Do you have a web server in front of Tomcat or anything like that? Perhaps you have `*.jsp` mapped through the proxy but not `/TestServlet`? Not enough information here in your question. Please provide as much detail as possible.

Comment: Yes I can run jsp but I can not run servlet over mapping, if you like I can send you login & pass of my account just check it?

Comment: Giving username and password to a total stranger sounds like a bad idea. Do you want to hire me?

Answer (score 0):

Put `"./TestServlet"` in form action attribute

```
<form action="./TestServlet">
//do your stuff here
</form>
```

or

directly call servlet

for localhost

```
 1.http://localhost:8080/TestServlet
```

for your domain

```
 2. http://DOMAIN PATH :APCHE TOMCAT PATH/TestServlet
```

Comment: which form?
<url-pattern>./TestServlet</url-pattern> this?

Comment: I dont want use form I want call directlly my servlet path, everything work very well on local host but when i upload on the server doesn't work, i have cpanel and tomcat 7 integrated to cpanel

Comment: How do I find out which path to tomcat?
that will looks like this
www.mydomain.com:tomcatPath/TestServlet
?

Comment: here is example
http://daviramos.com/TestServlet

if i set apache port that is the same
http://daviramos.com:80/TestServlet

Comment: i thing your tomcat is stop.

Comment: no tomcat work I can run .jsp files also I can run Servlet from jsp
but I can not mapping servlet

http://daviramos.com/jsptest.jsp

Comment: Here is example where I call servlet from jsp

http://daviramos.com/jsps.jsp

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="com.i_do2.java.TestServlet"%>
<%  
  TestServlet ts = new TestServlet();
  ts.service(request, response);
%>